# How can i use a value from my appSettings Configuration file, and use it in a constructor method as a decimal value?

Tags: c#

So I am in the process of working through a project.  Everything was working fine until i put some more control into my form, now it seems as though my tax rates I had set in my configuration file, won't be accepted by my constructor method at run time.

compiles fine, then when i open the form up from the MDi frame, I get this ArguementNullException Handled error and a troubleshoot window pops up.

After doing some researching i am thinking that when i pull my keys from the config file, i am not properly parsing them so that my constructor will take them at run-time.

here's the code that i wrote, im not posting my entire solution, that would be insane at this point.

```
// sales tax inititalization 
        decimal gstTax =     Decimal.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoodsAndServicesTaxRate."));
        decimal pstTax = Decimal.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ProvincialSalesTaxRate"));
        decimal salesTaxRate = gstTax + pstTax;


        SalesQuote quote = new SalesQuote(Decimal.Parse(txtSalePrice.Text),
                                        (Decimal.Parse(txtTradeIn.Text)),
                                        salesTaxRate,
                                        (Accessories)optA,
                                        (ExteriorFinish)optB);
```

And here is the XML file with the key values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationName:" value="RRC Automotive Group"/>
    <add key="GoodsAndServicesTaxRate" value=".05"/>
    <add key="ProvincialSalesTaxRate" value=".08"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And yes there is an assembly reference.

the signature for SalesQuote(decimal,decimal,decimal,Enum,Enum) if that wasn't already obvious.

i want to thank you fellow nerds for any advice... to the best of my knowledge this was all working fine so im not sure what is trumping me up here.

any help helps!
thanks

Comment: where do you get the argument null exception?

Comment: You have a stray `.` here `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoodsAndServicesTaxRate.")` which does not match up with what is in the config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray `.` here

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoodsAndServicesTaxRat‌​e.")
```

which does not match up with what is in the config file

```
<add key="GoodsAndServicesTaxRate" value="0.05"/>
```

This would result in the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get` method return `null` which would cause the parsing `Decimal.Parse` to fail.

Comment: OMG rookie move... sorry for wasting your time here

Comment: that actually didn't solve the issue i'm having.... the exception points to the constructor..  it reads as follows... :  Fomrat Exception Unhandled :input string is not in the correct format. (vs2010)  at runtime.

Comment: Which constructor? That is a new error. Also show exactly where you get the error.

Comment: @sneufeld, The only other pace I can see where the error is possible is `Decimal.Parse(txtSalePrice.Text),(Decimal.Parse(txtTradeIn.Text))`